# BCM2046 Bluetooth on new 8,3 MacBook Pro

Tags: linux, bluetooth

I recently was able to install and configure Ubuntu 11.10-amd64 on my new late 2011 8,3 MacBook Pro:

```
$ sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name
MacBookPro8,3
$ uname -a
Linux work-macbook 3.0.0-14-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 21 20:28:43 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Just about everything is working, with the major exception of Bluetooth. Bluetooth actually does show up in the app-indicator tray and I can try to connect to devices with it. It also shows up fine in `hcitool` output:

```
$ hcitool dev
Devices:
    hci0    60:C5:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

However, no matter how I try, I simply cannot get it to find pairable devices in the area, whether with the graphical tool or with `hcitool scan`.

The only way that it can successfully connect to things is when I use my Nexus One to initiate a pairing request with the machine (client-to-server), but it doesn't work the other way around, meaning that my Nexus One *can see and connect to the MacBook Pro*, but my MacBook Pro *cannot see nor connect to my Nexus One.*

I've tested multiple other devices as well to try and resolve the issue. Neither my Jawbone Aliph headset, nor my Motorola S305 headset, nor my Nexus One show up to the computer when it scans for them. By comparison, another computer in the area sees them almost immediately with `hcitool scan`. (The other computer is running LM11-amd64 with an ASUS USB Bluetooth dongle.)

I've tried just about everything I can think of here, but I'm sure there's something I'm not doing just right.

```
$ lsusb -v
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 05ac:821a Apple, Inc. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
  bDeviceSubClass         1 
  bDeviceProtocol         1 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x05ac Apple, Inc.
  idProduct          0x821a 
  bcdDevice            0.37
  iManufacturer           1 Apple Inc.
  iProduct                2 Bluetooth USB Host Controller
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          216
    bNumInterfaces          4
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       224 Wireless
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Radio Frequency
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0000  1x 0 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0000  1x 0 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       224 Wireless
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Radio Frequency
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0009  1x 9 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0009  1x 9 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       2
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       224 Wireless
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Radio Frequency
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0011  1x 17 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0011  1x 17 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       3
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       224 Wireless
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Radio Frequency
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0020  1x 32 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0020  1x 32 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       4
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       224 Wireless
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Radio Frequency
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       5
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       224 Wireless
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Radio Frequency
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0020  1x 32 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x04  EP 4 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0020  1x 32 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        3
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass       254 Application Specific Interface
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Device Firmware Update
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 
      iInterface              0 
      Device Firmware Upgrade Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                             7
        bDescriptorType                    33
        bmAttributes                        7
          Will Not Detach
          Manifestation Tolerant
          Upload Supported
          Download Supported
        wDetachTimeout                   5000 milliseconds
        wTransferSize                      64 bytes
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

I've provided a lot of relevant logs and configuration files below to try and help resolve this:

[`dmesg`](http://pastebin.com/EUxD1J2D) output.
[`lsusb -v`](http://pastebin.com/rdRJUsxv) output.
[`hciconfig`](http://pastebin.com/2S0ReqBU) output.
[`/etc/default/bluetooth`](http://pastebin.com/jyqaj8Q1) conf file.
[`/etc/bluetooth/input.conf`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/784737/) conf file.
[`/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/784738/) conf file.
[`/etc/bluetooth/serial.conf`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/784739/) conf file.
[`/etc/bluetooth/network.conf`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/784740/) conf file.
[`/etc/bluetooth/rfcomm.conf`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/784741/) conf file.
[`/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/784743/) conf file.

Can anyone think of why this wouldn't be working? The BCM2046 driver seems to have been supported by Linux for a long time!

---

Update: if I add the device in OSX, then boot back into Linux, I can now find the device with `bluetooth-applet`, but it fails to connect to it. Hmm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so basically, I had to do the following.

Boot up in OSX, connect the device, get it paired.

Reboot into Ubuntu (or whatever), then do what's described [here](http://j.mp/vZxxMm) to make a few startup entries, specifically `/etc/xdg/autostart/bluetooth-*.desktop` visible in Startup Applications via setting `NoDisplay=false` on each of them. Open up Startup Applications and *disable* Bluetooth Applet.

Now, install `blueman` and start it up. Make sure that it's selected in Startup Applications:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:blueman/ppa && ( sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get install blueman )
```

Once done, restart and configure things using blueman rather than Ubuntu's default `bluetooth-applet`.

There are notably a few problems here, specifically that headphones and the like don't automatically connect, but that's for another question.

You're probably asking why you needed to boot into OSX to do this. Good question. Apparently, Lion stores a lot of configuration in firmware and does some pretty weird stuff with EFI to make this happen. I've noticed that changing certain things in Linux changes things in OSX and vice-versa. Super weird, but it's Apple.

Comment: For the record, it's not only Apple. This is suggested for Dell laptops as well:https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothSetup